# Error restarting rsyslog

Tags: debian, sysvinit, rsyslogd

When restarting rsyslogd in Debian, it gives me the rather cryptic error:

```
rsyslogd: error reading pid file, cannot start up
rsyslogd: run failed with error -3000 (see rsyslog.h or try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 to learn what that number means)
```

I have tried looking it up online, the mentioned URL gives an error, other search results suggest issues with SELinux, but I do not even use it in this server.

What is it the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, the first line in the error about creating the pid is the clue for the problem.

Using `df -h`, we noticed our `/run` partition was out of space. Increasing it in `/etc/fstab` (it is not there in Debian by default, but we have an entry), or editing the directive in `RUN_SIZE` in `/etc/default/tmpfs`, to increase the allowed size, takes care of the problem.

After modifying the above file, the size will be reflect, either in the next reboot, or doing:

```
mount -o remount /run
```

If starting `rsyslogd` still does not work, it is also needed to perform an extra step, that is deleting a dangling pid file, and possibly killing any extra runaway rsyslogd processes, which may or not exist.

```
rm /run/rsyslogd.pid
pkill -9 rsyslogd
service rsyslogd start
```

Comment: It's `RUN_SIZE`, and it and the entire `/etc/default/tmpfs` are no longer used on systemd Debian.  `/etc/fstab` or an explicitly written `run.mount` unit are the ways to proceed on systemd Debian.  Of course, the PID file rubbish is completely unnecessary under a service manager in the first place.

Comment: Thxs for pointing it out. Obviously I am not running systemd. Corrected the variable, and added the tag `sysvinit` to the question.